# How can I set temporary path variables for conda running on windows inside of WSL

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to make it so I can execute my windows anaconda's conda command from WSL. However it cannot connect because the correct path variables are not set up.

Where the alias is just defined in bashrc with:

```
CONDA_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3
alias conda="$CONDA_PATH/Scripts/conda.exe"
```

Executing results in

```
michael@DESKTOP-OI3AOU6:~$ conda update conda
Collecting package metadata: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anacon
da.com/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on
your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please fi
le
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\',
 port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.j
son.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available."))'))
```

---

I read that certain paths need to be included in the path for the conda.exe to function:

- Anaconda3/
- Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin
- Anaconda3/Library/bin
- Anaconda3/Scripts

I do not want to have these directories allways sitting in my path, so I temporarily set the path with:

```
CONDA_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3
PATH_APPENDS=$CONDA_PATH:$CONDA_PATH/Library/mingw-w64/bin:$CONDA_PATH
/Library/bin:$CONDA_PATH/Scripts
alias conda="PATH=$PATH:$PATH_APPENDS conda.exe"
```

which results in an error message:

```
michael@DESKTOP-OI3AOU6:~$ conda
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

---

Here is the total path:

```
michael@DESKTOP-OI3AOU6:~$ echo $PATH:$PATH_APPENDS /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft MPI/Bin:/mnt/c/VulkanSDK/1.1.101.0/Bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet:/mnt/c/Users/spong/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/spong/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/texlive/2018/bin/win32:/mnt/c/Users/spong/bin:/snap/bin:/home/michael/.cargo/bin:/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3:/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin:/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Library/bin:/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Scripts
```

So for some reason the parentheses carried over in the path are now becoming an issue on the line.

---

Here is my the  section on my .bashrc

> ```
> ## Conda Aliases
> # Adding conda as an alias to the anaconda installation in the home dir
> # Conda requires the following path to function:
> # Anaconda3/
> # Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin
> # Anaconda3/Library/bin
> # Anaconda3/Scripts
>
> CONDA_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3
> PATH_APPENDS=$CONDA_PATH:$CONDA_PATH/Library/mingw-w64/bin:$CONDA_PATH
> /Library/bin:$CONDA_PATH/Scripts
> alias conda="PATH=$PATH:$PATH_APPENDS conda.exe"
> #alias conda="$CONDA_PATH/Scripts/conda.exe"
> alias conda-cheatsheet="\$(cd $CONDA_PATH;mupdf.exe conda-cheatsheet.pd
> f)"
> alias ipython="$CONDA_PATH/Scripts/ipython3.exe"
> alias jupyter-notebook="$CONDA_PATH/Scripts/jupyter-notebook.exe --no-b
> rowser"
> alias anaconda-navigator="$CONDA_PATH/Scripts/anaconda-navigator.exe"
> ```

---

Output of `type conda`:

```
michael@DESKTOP-OI3AOU6:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ type conda
conda is aliased to `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft MPI/Bin:/mnt/c/VulkanSDK/1.1.101.0/Bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet:/mnt/c/Users/spong/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/spong/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/texlive/2018/bin/win32:/mnt/c/Users/spong/bin:/snap/bin:/home/michael/.cargo/bin:/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3:/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin:/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Library/bin:/mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Scripts" /mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses in this portion of the PATH may be causing the issue

```
:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:
```

Trying adding backslash-escaped double quotes when defining the alias:

```
alias conda="PATH=\"$PATH:$PATH_APPENDS\" conda.exe"
```

Comment: Well that fixed the alias command. Now it reverts too the CondaHTTP error as it doesnt seem to use the linked paths.

Comment: Can you do a `which conda` and post the output so that we can verify the expected Anaconda-related paths are included in the PATH?

Comment: `which conda` Is not returning anything. After I commit all the paths to my actual path whereis shows up as: `michael@DESKTOP-OI3AOU6:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ whereis conda.exe
conda: /mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Library/bin/conda.bat
michael@DESKTOP-OI3AOU6:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ whereis conda
conda: /mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Library/bin/conda.bat`. The location of conda.exe is /mnt/c/Users/spong/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `type conda`.   Can you try that and post the output?

Comment: I added it to the post as it maxes out the char limit.

Comment: The `type conda` output shows that the environment variables are being properly substituted in the alias definition.  Do you still get the CondaHTTP error if you don’t use the alias and instead, do the following from the command line:  (1) Type `unalias conda` to remove the alias (2) set PATH manually to the value in the `type conda` output you added to the original post (3) run `conda.exe`?  I know that the whole point is to avoid permanently putting the Ananconda directories into the PATH, but this should help rule out something other than the alias causing the issue.

Comment: I unaliased it, manually set the full path, and ran it and it still ended up with the error. This may just be an error on how WSL handles path. trying to run other things directly in the command prompt ended up with file not found error, even though tab completion finds the files there.